# Holding touchpad button detect multitouch

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I just swiched over to Kubuntu from Windows. Everything works for now, except 1 thing realy bothers me.

I have asus N750 with touchpad.

In windows, if I had my finger placed on left button, I was able to move mouse with another finger moving on pad. On linux this is automaticly detectede as multouch gesture and will not work as intented.

Maybe the picture can explain better.

[image]

so what happens is. If i have finger 1 down on red dot, and move finger 2 from green 1 to green 2 it will not detect mouse move.

Is there anything i can do to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem when using my Asus touchpad in Debian. Ubuntu works for me though, have you tried to install additional drivers?

Answer (score 1):

This worked on my Asus Q600a.

Remove and re-installing following two packages could solve your issue:

```
xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Follow these steps to remove completely and install it again.

```
Open terminal and execute following command:

sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-multitouch

be sure you don't remove any other package than xserver-xorg-input-multitouch

sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

again follow the same precaution.

Once removed execute these commands to install it again:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

again be sure you don't remove any other packages while installing it.

Once installed execute following commands to reconfigure it:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
sudo update-initramfs -u

Then restart your system.
```

There is a GUI application for setting up your touchpad.  Mine shows in Dash as "Pointing Devices".  Gives you control of most of your touchpad features.

Go to the Software Center and search for "Pointing Devices" that will also be the name in Dash.

Comment: I have tested the Pointing Devices GUI on both Ubuntu and Kubuntu, both versions are 14.04.  It actually has more options and seems to be smoother on Kubuntu.  In the first tab, be sure to click "Enable locked drags".  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Its still works same as before, sorry :(

Comment: What I mean with Finger 1 down, is, I have it places on button not preseed! maybe  this will help