# Lenovo T430U Touchpad multitouch won't work - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, multi-touch

I'm having trouble with the touchpad of my Lenovo T430U, the multitouch won't work. If I place my finger on the touchpad button, and try to move my other finger the system won't recognize the movement, it only works if I press the button.
This one ([Holding touchpad button detect multitouch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461604/holding-touchpad-button-detect-multitouch)) seems to have the same problem as I.